# Invalid typecast JSON

Tags: delphi

I have an "Invalid Class TypeCast" error when I try to execute the following code. The error is occurring on the highlighted line.

```pascal
procedure TFMLogin.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  jsonObj, jSubObj: TJSONObject;
  ja: TJSONArray;
  jv: TJSONValue;
  i, j, k: Integer;
begin
  Memo2.Clear;
  Fconex.datarax('/users.json');
  Memo2.Text:=FConex.ResponseJson;
  jsonObj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(memo2.Text), 0) as TJSONObject;
  ShowMessage('converted');

  for j := 0 to jsonObj.Size - 1 do
    //  if jsonObj.Get(j).JsonString.Value = 'users' then
  begin
    jv := jsonObj.Get(j).JsonValue;
    ShowMessage('1');
    ja := jv as TJSONArray; // <------------ ERROR
    ShowMessage('1.5');
    for i := 0 to ja.Size - 1 do
    begin
      jSubObj := (ja.Get(i) as TJSONObject);
      ShowMessage('2');
      for k := 0 to jSubObj.Size - 1 do
      begin
        if jSubObj.Get(k).JsonString.Value = 'mac' then
        begin
          memo3.lines.add(jSubObj.Get(k).JsonValue.Value);
          ShowMessage('3');
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

JSON to read/treat is this:

```
{
  "beg@hotmailcom":{
    "email":"beg@hotmail.com",
    "mac":"20-47-47-FE-97-DA",
    "pid":"true",
    "to":" 21/06/2022"
  },
  "fg@hotmail.com":{
    "email":"fg@hotmail.com",
    "mac":"20-47-47-FE-97-DA",
    "po":"true",
    "to":" 21/06/2022"
  }
}
```

Recently, I used this JSON file read syntax in the array and continues to work. However, in this example, this error occurs.

Comment: There is no array in the JSON you posted, so why do you expect a `TJSONArray`?

Comment: The JSON showed consists of 1 top-level object containing 2 child sub-objects. There is no array present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TJSONValue is the ancestor class for all the JSON classes defining string, object, array, number, boolean, true, false, and null values.

For any JSONValu to be typecast as any of its descendants, the JSONValue should hold a compatible type.

In the sample JSON you have given, there is no array. So, the requested typecasting cannot take place.

Your JSON should have been something like this for the above typecast to happen correctly.

```
{
  "beg@hotmailcom":["beg@hotmail.com","20-47-47-FE-97-DA", "true", " 21/06/2022"]
  
}
```

Comment: Nice, that helped a lot.